# How to adjust the the plots in a column

Tags: plotting

I have two plots p1, p2 How to reduce the size of the plot p2 such that it's heigh should be small compared to p1. And also I am interested in putting a common label for both the plots for the x-axis, and it should be in the p2 plot?

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[3*\[Pi]*x], {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All];
p2 = Plot[Sin[1*\[Pi]*x], {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All];
Column[{p1, p2}, Spacings -> 0]
```

Comment: It is not quite clear, what do you want to achieve? There are no labels on you plot. Are you sure that you have labels in mind, rather than ticks? If it about ticks, try `FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {None, None}}` for p1 and leave it as it is in p2. Further, in your code the common ticks for the x-axis are already there. Further, you may fix the `ImageSize` to your liking. In this case, however, it is not clear how do you intend to position the plots with respect to one another. I guess that I would try to do it using the `Grid` statement and varying the sizes of the grid cells.

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch I have added a picture in my OP. Hope my question is clear now

Comment: No, since from you code I generated a picture which is different from your image.

Comment: I have changed my OP now entirely, is It clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[3*\[Pi]*x], {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {None, None}}, 
   ImageSize -> {300, Automatic}];
p2 = Plot[Sin[1*\[Pi]*x], {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/3, ImageSize -> {333, Automatic}];
GraphicsColumn[{p1, p2}, Spacings -> -61]
```

[image]

and play with the `AspectRatio`, `ImageSize` for p2 and `Spacings` for the `GraphicsColunmn`, to obtain the relation between two images that you need.

Have fun!

Comment: It is a kind of trial and error, cannot generalize it for all kinds of plots. I have 29 such plots, it will be laborious if I start tweaking for all 29. Is there any other way ?

Comment: @acoustics No that I see at once. If, however, they are of the same mutual size, the settings may be the same.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Do you know any ways to make it work along the lines of the "Scope" examples in [PlotLayout](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLayout.html) ?

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what  No idea. May be one my  problem is that I do not understand, why the OP needs what he needs.

Comment: Actually I am preparing plots for a journal paper, I wanted to plot like that to convey some information

Comment: Yes, this is clear. Unclear is why the second plot should be vertically compressed. What impression do you want to achieve? I take it, you looked into  PlotLayout? Does it help? Another advice: for the journal publication it is good to wrap the image by `Rasterize`.